# Firebase messaging importScripts is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I write a WEB application on the platform **Firebase**

I have a file *"firebase-messaging-sw.js"*, and when I access the file from *home.html* page, I get an error:

> importScripts is not

File *"firebase-messaging-sw.js"* is at the root level.

home.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:901px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mhome.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:900px)" />

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        ...
    </header>

    <div class="function">
        ...
    </div>

    <footer>
        ...
    </footer>

    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-performance.js"></script>

    <script src="javaScript/initFirebase.js"></script>
    <script src="javaScript/homeFirebase.js"></script> 
    <script src="javaScript/initHomePage.js"></script> 
    <script src="javaScript/latlon-geohash.js"></script> 

    <script src="firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>

</body>
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.3/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': '123456654321'
});
```

Help fix the error! Thank!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`firebase-messaging-sw.js` is service worker JavaScript file.

So you should not load JavaScript file using `<script src="firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>`.

Remove `<script src="firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>` and try the following code.

```
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
        });
      }
    </script>
```

See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#register_a_service_worker

Comment: congratulations! Could you accept my answer? And do you have any question 
 about how to send FCM notification? Could you post it in stack overflow?

Comment: aahhh this thing took my whole day, thanks man u saved my rest of the day